# Is there an Noetherian ring (commutative) with exactly three prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Is there an Noetherian ring (commutative) with exactly three prime ideals $P_i$ which satisfies the following statements?

1. $P_1P_2=0$ and $P_3P_3=0$
2. $P_1P_3\neq 0$ and $P_2P_3\neq 0$

Comment: We can use the argument of the answer to prove a more general statement. No three distinct prime ideals of any commutative ring satisfy condition 1.

Comment: In the case I change the first condition with $P_1P_2=0$ and there exists an ideal(not necessary prime) such that $P_3I=0$ then can find such a ring?

Comment: How about localizing $\mathbb Z[x]/(2x)$ at $(2,x)$?

Comment: Could you please explain it more!

Comment: The example I gave doesn't work, as $(2,x)f\subset(2x)$ implies $f\in(2x)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707334

Answer (score 7):

No; since $P_1P_2=0 \subseteq P_3$, either $P_1 \subseteq P_3$ or $P_2 \subseteq P_3$. Moreover since $P_3^2=0$, $P_3$ is contained in both $P_1$ and $P_2$. Therefore, either $P_1=P_3$ or $P_2=P_3$, contradicting either $P_1P_3 \neq 0$ or $P_2P_3 \neq 0$ (since $P_3^2=0$).

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld In general, if $P$ is prime and $IJ\subseteq P$, then either $I \subseteq P$ or $J\subseteq P$. To prove it, suppose that neither inclusion holds; then there is $x \in I$ not in $P$ and $y \in I$ not in $P$, but $xy \in IJ \subseteq P$; by definition of a prime ideal, we must have $x \in P$ or $y \in P$, which contradicts the choice of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I took that into account just before you posted your comment, thanks for the explanation though.